# How can I manipulate the "Adobe Acrobat Reader (64-bit)" app within excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, adobe

I have some experience using VBA, and I am interested in using "Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library" to be able to open the adobe reader app within VBA and manipulate or extract information in adobe acrobat reader pdf files.

my error is attached.

[image]

The code below is what I am trying:

```
Public Sub DoSomething_Adobe()
    Dim AcroApp As CAcroApp
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App") 'ERROR IS HERE
    AcroApp.Show
End Sub
```

I was expecting this code to open the reader and maybe transfer control to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run this procedure, but only with adobe acrobat pro, which I had to get by getting the adobe creative cloud subscription. It will not work with the adobe acrobat reader, which is the free edition.